# Export-Excel returning unreadable results when pulling data from Access

Tags: excel, powershell

I am using the Export-Excel module to create a mapping file for a database migration. The two data sources are

1. Access (Source)
2. SQL Server (Destination)

When I pull data from SQL-Server and pipe it into  Export-Excel everything is fine. When I use data from Access it comes out unreadable, i.e.:

> 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
>
> cf522b78d86c486691226b40aa69e95c

The same data prints to screen without issue.

Here is the code I am using to both pull the data and export it to Excel:

```
Function Get-AccessData {
    param ($sql)

    Try {

        #Connection
        $Connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

        #Connection string
        $Connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= $($Settings.Files.access)"

        #create command and fill dataset
        $ConCommand = $Connection.CreateCommand()
        $ConCommand.CommandText = $SQL
        $OAdapt = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $ConCommand
        $DS     = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet
        $OAdapt.Fill($DS) | out-null

        return $DS
    }
    Catch {

        Set-Output "[!] Access database connection failed" -colour RED -logfilepath $log_prerequisites
        Set-Output "    Ensure that Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is installed" -colour RED -logfilepath $log_prerequisites
        Set-Output "$_" -logfilepath $log_prerequisites
        break
    }
}
((Get-AccessData -sql "SELECT DISTINCT positionfrom JobOrder").tables | format-table)


$JobTypes | Export-Excel $mFile_JobType -Autosize -FreezeTopRow -BoldTopRow -WorkSheetName "Job Types" -show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `format-table` from the next to last line. In PowerShell, anytime you use a `format-*` function you're basically saying "I don't care about this as an object anymore, give me plain text in particular format" (in this case, tabular).

But `Export-Excel` is expecting *data objects*, not plain text. So feed that to it.

```
(Get-AccessData -sql "SELECT DISTINCT positionfrom JobOrder").tables | Export-Excel $mFile_JobType -Autosize -FreezeTopRow -BoldTopRow -WorkSheetName "Job Types" -show
```

Comment: Thankyou, that worked, i also had to change it to .Tables.Columns.Table